# Generate unique pin numbers (6 digits) using current time and username + password?

Tags: c++, one-time-password

I need to use current time because later on, another program will need to know when I generated the pin and whats the username and password.

Summary:

- Username + password + current time = pin [6 digits]
- Reverse, generated pin, I need to know which particular, and check if its already pass 1 minute.

I am not asking for direct code, but I need to know the best, not say best, good way/algorithm for it. Thanks (btw, I am cpp beginner)

EDIT:

I am sorry for not making things clear. Actually, I dun need the OTP, after generated the pin, the other program will need to run like this: validate {username} {password} {pin}

Comment: All I can think of right now is a hash function that generates a 6 digit string in base 64.

Comment: @Red you won't be able to decode that afterwards

Comment: @sehe What do you mean by `OTP is purely random and secret` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

999999 minutes, gives ~694 days, ~1.9 years. So if you used all the entropy available just for recording the current time, you'd cycle the value in less than 2 years.

And things will be much worse if you want to include the username and password, and avoid easy guessing.

With 6 decimal digits, you can store about 19 bits of data. So you'll have to make sure that you have strong anti-brute-force protection on your server end, otherwise it'll be trivial to try all possible combinations.

[One-time passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) do not have internal decode-able structure, they are typically used in addition to a normal password to act as a second factor in authentication. Then can be based on the time as you are suggesting, but are not reversible - the other end also has the secret key, and can generate the possible list itself.

So, for example, as well as entering a username and (normal) password, the user enters the value from a token, which is generated as `AES(secretkey, currentminute)`, and the server computes `AES(secretkey, currentminute)` and `AES(secretkey, currentminute-1)` etc, to compare the value against. It might also record which token matches, so that it records an estimate of the token's clock accuracy, which allows some drift of the token's clock, as long as it's used frequently enough. To work out how to best use the 19 bits you have in a 6-digit pin, you'll need someone who is a real cryptographer - as I would guess that taking a simple truncation might be in-secure.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer. For the AES(secretkey, currentminute), the AES could be a md5 or something like that? Do you have any hash function that return digits only? I think md5 returns alphanumerics string

Comment: @generator Both AES and MD5 just return you bits, how you encode them is up to you. You need to use encryption, not hashing, as you need to have a shared secret between the two ends (as everyone knows what the current minute is).

Answer (score 1):

Promoted my earlier comment to an answer, as an afterthought:

> I'm pretty sure it is deceiving to call this 'otp'. OTP is purely random and secret.
>
> What you describe is a simple hash.
>
> You could

```
 MD5(username+password_hash+(seconds_past_1970%60))
```

> I'm sure besides using public key encryption instead of the password, this is more or less how RSA keys do it.

**Edit** Oh yes: it will be pretty trivial to generate 6 digits from the resulting hash :)

Comment: how would you do the reversed step?

Comment: @duedlOr: You cannot revert the process. 6 digits cannot hold enough information to encode all the information. Consider that a user could be using more than 6 digits just for the password.

Comment: @David: The goal I assumed was to validate the PIN on the server based on known shared secret. I assumed the OP knows that this is not (should not be) reversible, and he _actually meant_ to **repeat the steps** on the server (knowing the inputs and the time). Obviously, 6 digits is nowhere near enough to encode it, unless there is no entropy left and the input is very simple... this would lead to the pin number exposing the secrets in near plain text. That being absolutely useless, my answer seems the correct thing to suggest :)